Project poles to ground from a sampled curve
Given a 3D Bézier curve, how can I sample along the curve and draw a line from that point down to the ground plane?
I have this (focus on bottom third), which is letting me project a single point down:


Resample Curve feeds into Sample Curve, with a specific Factor selected.
The Position from Sample Curve is fed into Start and Start Handle of Bézier Segment, and into the Source Position of a Raycast going down to a ground plane.
The Hit Position of the Raycast becomes the End and End Handle of the Bézier Segment.
Curve to Mesh makes the Bézier segment thicker.

What I want is to not use Sample Curve, but instead use each point from Resample Curve:


I realize now I don't need to use Raycast to get to the ground plane; I can instead just decompose a point and set its $z$ to $0$. But I still can't figure out how to create a segment for each point that I've resampled.

My idea would have been to instance a vertical curve line on the resampled points.
Then after realizing the instances I use a Set Position node to multiply the Position of the endpoints (using Endpoint Selection) by vector (1, 1, 0) to set them to the floor (if the floor had a different Z height, I could also add a vector afterwards with the according Z value, which I'm not showing here).
Finally I create the poles with a Curve to Mesh node and a Curve Circle as Profile Curve.


Nice all-around, but I especially appreciate the simpler zero-ing out of z by multiplying by 1,1,0 instead of my more-cumbersome Separate+Combine.

I found a solution using Instance on Points. Instead of constructing pillars from Curve to Mesh on 2-point Bézier segments, I use:

Resample Curve to generate the points I want.
Capture Attribute on Position to grab the position of each point.
Modify each captured point to set the $z$ to $0$.
Use Instance on Points to place cylinder instances at each point.
Modify the Scale Z of the instances to make them reach the correct height.


